# Issue firing a valid cancel CellEditEvent when editing from one cell to another

Tags: javafx, tableview, javafx-8

I am implementing an editable `TableView` which relies on the `CellEditEvents` for cancel, start & commit events.

In the below example, the city column is editable, and the corresponding events are triggered when:

- Cancel: Pressing escape in text field or when the focus is lost from text field.
- Commit: Pressing enter in text field.

The start and cancel events are triggering properly when I traverse from an editing cell to the `RadioButton`. But it is throwing error when traversing from one cell to another.

Please check the below gif(for steps) and the console output.
[image]

```
On City edit start :: TableDataObj{firstName=First Name 0, lastName=Last Name 0, city=City 0}
On City edit cancel :: TableDataObj{firstName=First Name 0, lastName=Last Name 0, city=City 0}
On City edit start :: TableDataObj{firstName=First Name 1, lastName=Last Name 1, city=City 1}
On City edit cancel :: TableDataObj{firstName=First Name 1, lastName=Last Name 1, city=City 1}
On City edit start :: TableDataObj{firstName=First Name 0, lastName=Last Name 0, city=City 0}
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javafx.scene.control.TableColumn$CellEditEvent.getTableView(TableColumn.java:772)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableColumn$CellEditEvent.getRowValue(TableColumn.java:829)
    at com.thales.javafx.tableview.CancelTableEditDemo.lambda$buildTable$7(CancelTableEditDemo.java:84)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableCell.cancelEdit(TableCell.java:400)
    at com.thales.javafx.tableview.CancelTableEditDemo$EditingCell.cancelEdit(CancelTableEditDemo.java:105)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableCell.updateEditing(TableCell.java:565)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableCell.lambda$new$26(TableCell.java:142)
    at javafx.beans.WeakInvalidationListener.invalidated(WeakInvalidationListener.java:83)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:349)
    at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper$ReadOnlyPropertyImpl.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:176)
    at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:142)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:112)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableView.setEditingCell(TableView.java:1145)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableView.edit(TableView.java:1457)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TableCellBehavior.edit(TableCellBehavior.java:106)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TableCellBehavior.edit(TableCellBehavior.java:38)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.handleClicks(CellBehaviorBase.java:269)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TableCellBehaviorBase.simpleSelect(TableCellBehaviorBase.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TableCellBehaviorBase.doSelect(TableCellBehaviorBase.java:148)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.mousePressed(CellBehaviorBase.java:150)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:95)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:352)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$355(GlassViewEventHandler.java:388)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:387)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What I am expecting is : When traversing from Cell-0 to Cell-1, it has to fire a valid Cancel event for Cell-0 before start edit of Cell-1.

Can any of you please help me in figuring where/what I am missing?

Below is the full working code of the issue:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CancelTableEditDemo extends Application {
    public static void main(String... a) {
        Application.launch(a);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final ObservableList<TableDataObj> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        final int no = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < no; i++) {
            final String firstName = "First Name " + i;
            final String lastName = "Last Name " + i;
            final String city = "City " + i;
            items.add(new TableDataObj(i, firstName, lastName, city));
        }

        final TableView<TableDataObj> table = buildTable();
        table.setItems(items);

        final VBox root = new VBox(new RadioButton("Use this for focus changing"), table);
        root.setSpacing(10);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        VBox.setVgrow(table, Priority.ALWAYS);

        final Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Cancel Table Edit Demo");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private TableView<TableDataObj> buildTable() {
        final TableView<TableDataObj> tableView = new TableView<>();
        tableView.setEditable(true);
        final TableColumn<TableDataObj, Integer> idCol = new TableColumn<>();
        idCol.setText("Id");
        idCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().idProperty().asObject());

        final TableColumn<TableDataObj, String> fnCol = new TableColumn<>();
        fnCol.setText("First Name");
        fnCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().firstNameProperty());
        fnCol.setPrefWidth(150);

        final TableColumn<TableDataObj, String> lnCol = new TableColumn<>();
        lnCol.setText("Last Name");
        lnCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().lastNameProperty());
        lnCol.setPrefWidth(150);

        final TableColumn<TableDataObj, String> cityCol = new TableColumn<>();
        cityCol.setEditable(true);
        cityCol.setText("City");
        cityCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().cityProperty());
        cityCol.setPrefWidth(150);
        cityCol.setCellFactory(param -> {
            final EditingCell<TableDataObj, String> cell = new EditingCell<>();
            cell.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
                tableView.edit(cell.getTableRow().getIndex(), cityCol);
            });
            return cell;
        });
        cityCol.setOnEditStart(e -> {
            System.out.println("On City edit start :: " + e.getRowValue());
        });
        cityCol.setOnEditCancel(e -> {
            System.out.println("On City edit cancel :: " + e.getRowValue());
        });
        cityCol.setOnEditCommit(e -> {
            System.out.println("On City edit commit :: val : " + e.getNewValue() + " :: " + e.getRowValue());
            e.getRowValue().setCity(e.getNewValue());
        });
        tableView.getColumns().addAll(idCol, fnCol, lnCol, cityCol);
        return tableView;
    }

    /**
     * Editing Cell
     */
    class EditingCell<T, S> extends TableCell<T, S> {

        private TextField textField;

        @Override
        public void cancelEdit() {
            super.cancelEdit();
            updateItem(getItem(), getItem() == null);
        }

        @Override
        public void commitEdit(final S newValue) {
            super.commitEdit(newValue);
        }

        @Override
        public void startEdit() {
            super.startEdit();
            updateItem(getItem(), getItem() == null);
            textField.selectAll();
            textField.requestFocus();
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(final S item, final boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
            } else {
                if (isEditing()) {
                    if (textField == null) {
                        createTextField();
                    }
                    textField.setText(getString());
                    setGraphic(textField);
                    setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
                } else {
                    setText(item != null ? item.toString() : "");
                    setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
                }
            }
        }

        private void createTextField() {
            textField = new TextField(getString());
            textField.setMinWidth(getWidth() - getGraphicTextGap() * 2);

            textField.setOnKeyPressed(keyEvent -> {
                if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                    cancelEdit();
                    keyEvent.consume();
                } else if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                    commitEdit((S) textField.getText()); // For now casting directly for testing
                    keyEvent.consume();
                }
            });

            /* Cancel edit when loosing focus. */
            textField.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, prevFocus, focused) -> {
                if (!focused) {
                    cancelEdit();
                }
            });
        }

        private String getString() {
            return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Data object.
     */
    class TableDataObj {
        private final IntegerProperty id = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final StringProperty city = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public TableDataObj(final int i, final String fn, final String ln, final String cty) {
            setId(i);
            setFirstName(fn);
            setLastName(ln);
            setCity(cty);
        }

        public StringProperty cityProperty() {
            return city;
        }

        public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public String getCity() {
            return city.get();
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id.get();
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public IntegerProperty idProperty() {
            return id;
        }

        public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setCity(final String city1) {
            city.set(city1);
        }

        public void setFirstName(final String firstName1) {
            firstName.set(firstName1);
        }

        public void setId(final int idA) {
            id.set(idA);
        }

        public void setLastName(final String lastName1) {
            lastName.set(lastName1);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "TableDataObj{" +
                    "firstName=" + firstName.get() +
                    ", lastName=" + lastName.get() +
                    ", city=" + city.get() +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no screenshots of plain text please.. anyway, probably one of the many issues with cell editing many of which were fixed recently (fx17, 18)

Comment: btw: _When traversing from Cell-0 to Cell-1, it has to fire a valid Cancel event for Cell-0 before start edit of Cell-1_ is an incorrect assumption due to the mechanics of cell editing - cells are updating their own editing state from listeners to table's editing cell property. Depending on the sequence of listener installation, the cell at the new editing location might switch into editing mode while the cell at the old editing location has not yet switched off editing mode. The moral: don't base any logic on the assumed sequence :)

Comment: just tried: worksforme fx18+ - getting an NPE only if clicking into an empty cell

Comment: all that said: what are you trying to achieve _exactly_? If it is the infamous commit-on-focusLost .. there's are nothing but really dirty hacks to get it (even in fx18 - working on a real solution, a raw preview is at https://github.com/kleopatra/swingempire-fx/wiki/CellEditAPI)

Comment: Seems to work on JavaFX 17. "The `updateItem` method should not be called by developers," and I have to wonder if your `empty` parameter is always valid when bassed to `super`.

Comment: Firstly, I checked the issue in JavaFX17 and as you guys said.. it is fixed in it. Thanks for letting me know that. @kleopatra, thanks for correcting my assumption.

Comment: @trashgod thanks for reminding me of the doc of updateItem to not call this method directly.

Comment: While it may take a while for updating my project to FX17, i need to find a solution to make it work with FX8. Knowing that it is fixed in JavaFX17, i can confidently go with some hack temporarily. Thank you guys :)

Comment: @SaiDandem: I see the problem reliably on Java 8.

Comment: clarifying my first comment: _no screenshots of plain text please_ was meant as an hint to edit you question, a readable stacktrace is important for a complete question ;)

Comment: here the bug is in CellEditEvent: it's not always instantiated with the correct cell state - that in combination with fishy implementation leads to NPEs in its accessors, see f.i. https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8269871 and related issues (all fixed in fx17 and later). Look into implementations and expect everything to be null at unexpected times ;) for correct cell state you might fire an additional correctly configured event ... which is not always possbile due to cell pecularities .. an uphill effort ..

Comment: @kleopatra, I came up with the same approach of firing a correctly configured event. Posted my workaround as answer. Also updated the question to show the stacktrace as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. as I have to look for a workaround till I upgrade to JavaFX 17, below are the changes I came up with (for JavaFX 8):

Firstly, adding a null check for TablePosition in the onCancelEdit event handler to ensure no errors are thrown because of the internal bug.

```
cityCol.setOnEditCancel(e -> {
    if (e.getTablePosition() != null) {
        System.out.println("On City edit cancel :: " + e.getRowValue());
    }
});
```

Secondly, to fire the correct cancel event, I am explicitly firing the cancel event when the conditions are not correct.

```
@Override
public void cancelEdit() {
    TablePosition<T, ?> editingCell = getTableView().getEditingCell();
    super.cancelEdit();
    // If the editingCell is null, then the editCancelEvent fired in super method has no impact. So explicitly firing a valid editCancelEvent.
    if (editingCell == null) {
        final TablePosition<T, S> pos = new TablePosition<>(getTableView(), getTableRow().getIndex(), getTableColumn());
        Event.fireEvent(getTableColumn(), new TableColumn.CellEditEvent<>(getTableView(), pos, TableColumn.editCancelEvent(), null));
    }
    setText(getItem() != null ? getItem().toString() : "");
    setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
}
```

A full working demo with the changes is below:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CancelTableEditDemo extends Application {
    public static void main(String... a) {
        Application.launch(a);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final ObservableList<TableDataObj> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        final int no = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < no; i++) {
            final String firstName = "First Name " + i;
            final String lastName = "Last Name " + i;
            final String city = "City " + i;
            items.add(new TableDataObj(i, firstName, lastName, city));
        }

        final TableView<TableDataObj> table = buildTable();
        table.setItems(items);

        final VBox root = new VBox(new RadioButton("Use this for focus changing"), table);
        root.setSpacing(10);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        VBox.setVgrow(table, Priority.ALWAYS);

        final Scene sc = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(sc);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Cancel Table Edit Demo");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private TableView<TableDataObj> buildTable() {
        final TableView<TableDataObj> tableView = new TableView<>();
        tableView.setEditable(true);
        final TableColumn<TableDataObj, Integer> idCol = new TableColumn<>();
        idCol.setText("Id");
        idCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().idProperty().asObject());

        final TableColumn<TableDataObj, String> fnCol = new TableColumn<>();
        fnCol.setText("First Name");
        fnCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().firstNameProperty());
        fnCol.setPrefWidth(150);

        final TableColumn<TableDataObj, String> lnCol = new TableColumn<>();
        lnCol.setText("Last Name");
        lnCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().lastNameProperty());
        lnCol.setPrefWidth(150);

        final TableColumn<TableDataObj, String> cityCol = new TableColumn<>();
        cityCol.setEditable(true);
        cityCol.setText("City");
        cityCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().cityProperty());
        cityCol.setPrefWidth(150);
        cityCol.setCellFactory(param -> {
            final EditingCell<TableDataObj, String> cell = new EditingCell<>();
            cell.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
                tableView.edit(cell.getTableRow().getIndex(), cityCol);
            });
            return cell;
        });
        cityCol.setOnEditStart(e -> {
            System.out.println("On City edit start :: " + e.getRowValue());
        });
        cityCol.setOnEditCancel(e -> {
            if (e.getTablePosition() != null) {
                System.out.println("On City edit cancel :: " + e.getRowValue());
            }
        });
        cityCol.setOnEditCommit(e -> {
            System.out.println("On City edit commit :: val : " + e.getNewValue() + " :: " + e.getRowValue());
            e.getRowValue().setCity(e.getNewValue());
        });
        tableView.getColumns().addAll(idCol, fnCol, lnCol, cityCol);
        return tableView;
    }

    /**
     * Editing Cell
     */
    class EditingCell<T, S> extends TableCell<T, S> {

        private TextField textField;

        @Override
        public void cancelEdit() {
            TablePosition<T, ?> editingCell = getTableView().getEditingCell();
            super.cancelEdit();
            // If the editingCell is null, then the editCancelEvent fired in super method has no impact. So explicitly firing a valid editCancelEvent.
            if (editingCell == null) {
                final TablePosition<T, S> pos = new TablePosition<>(getTableView(), getTableRow().getIndex(), getTableColumn());
                Event.fireEvent(getTableColumn(), new TableColumn.CellEditEvent<>(getTableView(), pos, TableColumn.editCancelEvent(), null));
            }
            setText(getItem() != null ? getItem().toString() : "");
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
        }

        @Override
        public void startEdit() {
            super.startEdit();
            if (textField == null) {
                createTextField();
            }
            textField.setText(getString());
            setGraphic(textField);
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
            textField.selectAll();
            textField.requestFocus();
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(final S item, final boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            setGraphic(null);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(item != null ? item.toString() : "");
                setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
            }
        }

        private void createTextField() {
            textField = new TextField(getString());
            textField.setMinWidth(getWidth() - getGraphicTextGap() * 2);

            textField.setOnKeyPressed(keyEvent -> {
                if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                    cancelEdit();
                    keyEvent.consume();
                } else if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                    commitEdit((S) textField.getText()); // For now casting directly for testing
                    keyEvent.consume();
                }
            });

            /* Cancel edit when loosing focus. */
            textField.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, prevFocus, focused) -> {
                if (!focused && isEditing()) {
                    cancelEdit();
                }
            });
        }

        private String getString() {
            return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Data object.
     */
    class TableDataObj {
        private final IntegerProperty id = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final StringProperty city = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public TableDataObj(final int i, final String fn, final String ln, final String cty) {
            setId(i);
            setFirstName(fn);
            setLastName(ln);
            setCity(cty);
        }

        public StringProperty cityProperty() {
            return city;
        }

        public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public String getCity() {
            return city.get();
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id.get();
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public IntegerProperty idProperty() {
            return id;
        }

        public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setCity(final String city1) {
            city.set(city1);
        }

        public void setFirstName(final String firstName1) {
            firstName.set(firstName1);
        }

        public void setId(final int idA) {
            id.set(idA);
        }

        public void setLastName(final String lastName1) {
            lastName.set(lastName1);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "TableDataObj{" +
                    "firstName=" + firstName.get() +
                    ", lastName=" + lastName.get() +
                    ", city=" + city.get() +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: good if that helps :) Beware: the current cell index at the time of cancelEdit might not point to the previous edit location see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8266969 and related for details

Answer (score 0):

**1. Avoid use of Platform.runLater(()-> "calls") !**

If the cell methods aren't triggering, reconsider the use of table/tree.getSelectionModel().clearSelection(). I encountered a situation where removing this call proved beneficial. In my scenario, I added a new TreeItem to the model and wanted to edit it immediately. While setting the focus and selection index was necessary, omitting the clearSelection() call worked in this context.

**2. Ensure there are no additional statements between table/tree.layout() and edit(), such as refresh() or similar functions. Place layout() on the line just before edit() to avoid any interference!**

For proper sorting, remember to call clearSelection() before adding a new item; otherwise, the selected index may be incorrect after sorting. However, including this call resulted in edit() not initiating the editing mode as expected. But that was not the actual reason in my case why it didn't start. It was because I had a listener for changes in the selections of the TreeView, which consequently logged the new selection into a selection history. This history, in turn, had a listener for changes in the list, and it would then call treeView.requestFocus(), abruptly ending the edit mode. It was challenging to identify since I didn't receive any error messages.

**3. Therefore, keep an eye on listeners that manipulate the focus when the selection changes, especially through the addition or removal of items!**